# Configure TFS 2018 build agent with no internet access

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild, azure-service-fabric

I configured a TFS 2018 [On-premises] agent pool and scheduled a build. Used the "Service fabric build template". Build failed with the following error

> No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
>   msbuild
>   visualstudio
>   Cmd
>   Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0

- In the "demands" section of build definition, "msbuild" and "visual studio" are mentioned as required and cannot be removed. why are these required?
- Our build machines are inside the firewall and do not have public internet access. I thought I can download the full ISO's on another machine and copy them to the build server. Looks like Microsoft does not provide offline installers for Visual studio 2017 and msbuild. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Used vsenterprise.exe --layout option to download from internet. So, problem # 2 is solved. [See Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mapo/2017/03/13/visual-studio-2017-offline-installer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those demands can't be removed because you are using tasks in your build that rely on them. Tasks can (and do) express "Demands" that have to be met by the agent's "Capabilities".

Installing Visual Studio and restarting your build agent should satisfy the demands.